# Changing a hyperlink to a CSS button

Tags: html, css, button, cookies

I have a .JS cookie script from, "https://cookieinfoscript.com/" and I am trying to change the bottom link, "EXIT" to mimic the top button, "ACCEPT COOKIE". I have tried everything but can't seem to do it.

Here is a link to my Codepen: https://codepen.io/brandon-humphrey/pen/mdEQwrN

```
!function(e){"use strict";var t=e,i=t.document,o="cbinstance";var n={get:function(e){return decodeURIComponent(i.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*"+encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g,"\\$&")+"\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"),"$1"))||null},set:function(e,t,o,n,s,r){if(!e||/^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(e))return!1;var a="";if(o)switch(o.constructor){case Number:a=o===1/0?"; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT":"; max-age="+o;break;case String:a="; expires="+o;break;case Date:a="; expires="+o.toUTCString()}return i.cookie=encodeURIComponent(e)+"="+encodeURIComponent(t)+a+(s?"; domain="+s:"")+(n?"; path="+n:"")+(r?"; secure":""),!0},has:function(e){return new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)"+encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g,"\\$&")+"\\s*\\=").test(i.cookie)},remove:function(e,t,o){return!(!e||!this.has(e))&&(i.cookie=encodeURIComponent(e)+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"+(o?"; domain="+o:"")+(t?"; path="+t:""),!0)}},s={merge:function(){var e,t={},i=0,o=arguments.length;if(0===o)return t;for(;i<o;i++)for(e in arguments[i])Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arguments[i],e)&&(t[e]=arguments[i][e]);return t},str2bool:function(e){switch((e=""+e).toLowerCase()){case"false":case"no":case"0":case"":return!1;default:return!0}},fade_in:function(e){e.style.opacity<1&&(e.style.opacity=(parseFloat(e.style.opacity)+.05).toFixed(2),t.setTimeout(function(){s.fade_in(e)},50))},get_data_attribs:function(e){var t={};if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,"dataset"))t=e.dataset;else{var i,o=e.attributes;for(i in o)if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,i)){var n=o[i];if(/^data-/.test(n.name))t[s.camelize(n.name.substr(5))]=n.value}}return t},normalize_keys:function(e){var t={};for(var i in e)if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,i)){var o=s.camelize(i);t[o]=e[o]?e[o]:e[i]}return t},camelize:function(e){for(var t="-",i=e.indexOf(t);-1!=i;){var o=i===e.length-1,n=o?"":e[i+1],s=n.toUpperCase(),r=o?t:t+n;i=(e=e.replace(r,s)).indexOf(t)}return e},find_script_by_id:function(e){for(var t=i.getElementsByTagName("script"),o=0,n=t.length;o<n;o++)if(e===t[o].id)return t[o];return null}},r=s.find_script_by_id("cookieinfo"),a=e.cookieinfo=function(e){this.init(e)};a.prototype={cookiejar:n,init:function(t){this.inserted=!1,this.closed=!1,this.test_mode=!1;if(this.default_options={cookie:"we-love-cookies",closeText:"ACCEPT COOKIE",cookiePath:"/",debug:!1,expires:1/0,zindex:1e20,mask:!1,maskOpacity:.5,maskBackground:"#999",height:"auto",minHeight:"19px",bg:"#CACACA",fg:"#000000",link:"#31A8F0",divlink:"#000",divlinkbg:"#5CB3FF",position:"bottom",message:"http://website.com.to is an online file storage for my tools. http://website.com.to is an online file storage for my tools. http://website.com.to is an online file storage for my tools.",linkmsg:"EXIT",scriptmsg:"Cookie Info Script",moreinfo:"http://google.ca",scriptinfo:"https://cookieinfoscript.com",tracking:"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",effect:null,fontSize:"14px",fontFamily:"verdana, arial, sans-serif",instance:o,textAlign:"left",acceptOnScroll:!1},this.options=this.default_options,this.script_el=r,this.script_el){var i=s.get_data_attribs(this.script_el);this.options=s.merge(this.options,i)}t&&(t=s.normalize_keys(t),this.options=s.merge(this.options,t)),o=this.options.instance,this.options.zindex=parseInt(this.options.zindex,10),this.options.mask=s.str2bool(this.options.mask),"string"==typeof this.options.expires&&"function"==typeof e[this.options.expires]&&(this.options.expires=e[this.options.expires]),"function"==typeof this.options.expires&&(this.options.expires=this.options.expires()),this.script_el&&this.run()},log:function(){"undefined"!=typeof console&&console.log.apply(console,arguments)},run:function(){if(!this.agreed()){var e=this;!function(e,t){var i=!1,o=!0,n=e.document,s=n.documentElement,r=n.addEventListener?"addEventListener":"attachEvent",a=n.addEventListener?"removeEventListener":"detachEvent",c=n.addEventListener?"":"on",l=function(o){"readystatechange"==o.type&&"complete"!=n.readyState||(("load"==o.type?e:n)[a](c+o.type,l,!1),!i&&(i=!0)&&t.call(e,o.type||o))},p=function(){try{s.doScroll("left")}catch(e){return void setTimeout(p,50)}l("poll")};if("complete"==n.readyState)t.call(e,"lazy");else{if(n.createEventObject&&s.doScroll){try{o=!e.frameElement}catch(e){}o&&p()}n[r](c+"DOMContentLoaded",l,!1),n[r](c+"readystatechange",l,!1),e[r](c+"load",l,!1)}}(t,function(){e.insert()})}},build_viewport_mask:function(){var e=null;if(!0===this.options.mask){var t=this.options.maskOpacity,o='<div id="cookieinfo-mask" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:'+this.options.maskBackground+";zoom:1;filter:alpha(opacity="+100*t+");opacity:"+t+";z-index:"+this.options.zindex+';"></div>',n=i.createElement("div");n.innerHTML=o,e=n.firstChild}return e},agree:function(){return this.cookiejar.set(this.options.cookie,1,this.options.expires,this.options.cookiePath),!0},agreed:function(){return this.cookiejar.has(this.options.cookie)},close:function(){return this.inserted&&(this.closed||(this.element&&this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element),this.element_mask&&this.element_mask.parentNode.removeChild(this.element_mask),this.closed=!0)),this.closed},agree_and_close:function(){return this.agree(),this.close()},cleanup:function(){return this.close(),this.unload()},unload:function(){return this.script_el&&this.script_el.parentNode.removeChild(this.script_el),e[o]=void 0,!0},insert:function(){this.element_mask=this.build_viewport_mask();var e=this.options.zindex;this.element_mask&&(e+=1);var t=i.createElement("div");t.className="cookieinfo",t.style.position="fixed",t.style.left=0,t.style.right=0,t.style.height=this.options.height,t.style.minHeight=this.options.minHeight,t.style.zIndex=e,t.style.background=this.options.bg,t.style.color=this.options.fg,t.style.lineHeight=t.style.minHeight,t.style.padding="8px 18px",t.style.fontFamily=this.options.fontFamily,t.style.fontSize=this.options.fontSize,t.style.textAlign=this.options.textAlign,"top"===this.options.position?t.style.top=0:t.style.bottom=0,t.innerHTML='<div class="cookieinfo-close" style="float:top;display:block;padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;min-width:100px;margin-left:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;border-top-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;">'+this.options.closeText+'</div><span style="display:block;padding:5px 0 5px 0;">'+this.options.message+" <a>"+this.options.linkmsg+"</a><img> <a>"+this.options.scriptmsg+"</a></span>",this.element=t;var o=t.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];o.href=this.options.moreinfo,o.style.textDecoration="none",o.style.color=this.options.link;var n=t.getElementsByTagName("a")[1];n.href=this.options.scriptinfo,n.style.textDecoration="none",n.style.display="none",n.style.color=this.options.link;var r=t.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];r.style.cursor="pointer",r.style.color=this.options.divlink,r.style.background=this.options.divlinkbg,r.style.textAlign="center";var a=t.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];function c(e,t,i){var o=e.addEventListener?"addEventListener":"attachEvent",n=e.addEventListener?"":"on";e[o](n+t,i,!1)}a.src=this.options.tracking,a.style.display="none";var l=this;c(r,"click",function(){l.agree_and_close()}),this.element_mask&&(c(this.element_mask,"click",function(){l.agree_and_close()}),i.body.appendChild(this.element_mask)),this.options.acceptOnScroll&&c(window,"scroll",function(){l.agree_and_close()}),i.body.appendChild(this.element),this.inserted=!0,"fade"===this.options.effect?(this.element.style.opacity=0,s.fade_in(this.element)):this.element.style.opacity=1}},r&&(e[o]||(e[o]=new a))}(window);
```

[Screenshot from my CodePen Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScHad.png)

Comment: Do you have a de-minified version of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an edit to your pen, checkout the link below:
https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/mdEQwXy?editors=0110

You need to add this style in your css file:

```css
.cookieinfo > span > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000 !important;
    background: rgb(92, 179, 255);
    text-align: center;
}
```

I had to use `.cookieinfo > span > a`, as id or classname is not present in the auto generated code.